# Стилизация popup menu, кнопки

Tags: android

Добрый вечер. 
Появилось несколько вопросов.
Вопрос 1. У меня есть кнопка.
 Ее код такой:

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_menu"/>
```

Файл button_menu:

```
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
       <shape android:shape="rectangle">
          <solid android:color="#d1d4d3"/>
      </shape>
    </item>
 </selector>
```

Кнопка рисуется, с этим все хорошо. В эту кнопку мне нужно впихнуть две маленькие картинки. Одну картинку справа и одну картинку слева. По середине должно быть место для текста. Текст задается программно - его размер неизвестен, т.е. он может быть как длинным, так и коротким.Получается, что положение картинки слева остается неизменным, а вот положение картинки справа зависит от длинны текста кнопки.

Вопрос 2. У меня есть popup menu. Как можно изменить цвет popup menu и его прозрачность? Как с обычной кнопкой не получается.
Вот код popup menu:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
    android:id="@+id/menu2"
    android:title="О приложении"/>
 <item
    android:id="@+id/menu3"
    android:title="Выйти из приложения"/>
 </menu>
```

**ОБНОВЛЕНО**

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_menu" >

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/left_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toLeftOf = "@id/left_image"
    android:singleLine = "true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf = "@+id/right_image"/>

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/right_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image2" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

   </RelativeLayout>

  View cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);
  actionBar.setCustomView(cView);
  Button button_actionbar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_button);
  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
  button.setText("ТекстМеждуКнопками");
  button_actionbar.setOnClickListener(viewClickListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

первый вопрос:

пихаешь эти 3 элемента в **RelativeLayout**.

для левой картинки свойство выставляешь **alignParenLeft = true**,

для центрального текста: **to_leftof = "id_твоей картинки слева"**, **singleline = true,
layout_width и layout_height выставляешь fill_parent, to_rightof = "id_картинки справа"**

для правой картинки пишешь **alignparent_right = true**

на сам relative_layout selector назначишь

[второй вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271942/how-to-create-a-custom-popup-menu)

Comment: посмотрите, пожалуйста, я обновил вопрос.

Comment: да, правильно понял.
то что на imageview ругается, это не помешает нормальной работе

чтобы все нажималось как единое целое тогда тебе надо сделать так:
присвоить id для relativeLayout, в котором у тебя 2 картинки и кнопка, найти его методом findViewById, определить для него onClickListener

Comment: Теперь приложение вылетает.. Посмотрите,пожалуйста,как я сделал. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: замени

Button button_actionbar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_button);

на

RelativeLayout button_actionbar = (RelativeLayout) cView.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_button);

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Теперь надо попробовать с popup menu разобраться. 
Ту ссылку я уже давно видел, но не увидел как там можно использовать для popup menu. Мне нужно просто изменить фон в открывающемся меню, его прозрачность и соответственно, при нажатии на элемент меню изменить его цвет (например через selector).

Comment: по ссылке, которую я привел, описывается альтернативный метод создания popup меню - с помощью alert dialog. поверь, его намного проще кастомизировать, чем ковыряться с меню. 
вот 2 ссылочки, тут примеры поинтереснее:

http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-display-custom-dialog-and.html

http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/04/animated-customized-popup-transparent.html